# PyQt: terminate worker thread on closeEvent

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qthread, terminate

I'm writing a GUI using PyQt.
I've a worker thread that I want to kill when I press the 'X' button in the top right corner.
So far I tried:

```
class Gui(QtGui.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super(OneTestGui, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.runner_thread = Runner(ui=self.ui)
    self.runner_thread = QtCore.QThread()
    self.runner_thread.moveToThread(self.runner_thread)
    self.runner_thread.start()

.
.
.

def closeEvent(self, event):
    result = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self,
                                        "Confirm Exit...",
                                        "Are you sure you want to exit ?",
                                        QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

    if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        print self.runner_thread.isRunning()
        if self.runner_thread.isRunning():
            self.runner_thread.terminate()
            self.runner_thread.wait()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

But when I press yes and the application closes I get in the terminal:

```
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.
```

I've tried installing event filter to self, self.ui and self.runner_thread as suggested here: [link](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2007-September/017161.html) but it didn't help and I have no idea where and how to reimplement QApplication::notify().

Am I doing something wrong and there is a proper way to killing the runner thread?

Comment: AFAIK the problem is that your `closeEvent` is raising an exception... did you try to check which exception it is? `try: if self.runner_thread.isRunning(): .... except Exception as e: traceback.print_exc() raise e` depending on what is happening you may be able to just catch the exception and ignore it or change your approach...

Comment: The problem is at self.runner_thread.terminate() and the try-except doesn't catch it... Do you have any suggestions for a different approach?

Comment: did you try to change `except Exception as e:` to `except BaseException as e:`.  The `terminate` call may be triggering a system-exit exception.  Anyway I believe you should **not** call `terminate` at all. The [documentation warns that `terminate` should be avoided](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#terminate), you should use [`QThread.quit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#quit).

Comment: I've changed to quit and it seemed to be working ok now.
Thanks!